# Problem with NaN values in a zonal_statistic Python script

Tags: python, numpy, nodata, rasterstats

I want to create a script to extract zonal statistics from all bands of tif files in a directory using each feature contained in a shapefile.

I use the nodata value of the image to avoid using those nodata pixels in the zonal statistics calculation. However, it seems that pixels with values different from nodata are also being considered as nodata.

I am testing the script with tif files with values 0 and 1, being 0 the nodata value.

The output look like:
[image]

I know the result is wrong because there are several features that intersect pixels with data.

Here the full code:

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
import rasterstats
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import numpy as np


def zonal_stats(input_tif_dir, shapefile):
       
    # Define the input directory containing the shapefile of polygons
    polygons = gpd.read_file(shapefile)
    shp_name = shapefile.rsplit('\\', 1)[1].rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    
    zs_full_df = pd.DataFrame()
    # Loop through each TIFF file in the input directory
    for file in os.listdir(input_tif_dir):
        if file.endswith('.tif'):
            # Open the TIFF file and get the raster data and transform
            tif_file = os.path.join(input_tif_dir, file)
    
            with rasterio.open(tif_file) as src:
    
                zs_bands = []
                num_bands=src.count
                for band in range(num_bands):
                    data = src.read(band+1)
                    transform = src.transform
                    nodata = src.nodata
                    data = data.astype('float64')
                    data[data == nodata] = np.nan
    
                    zs = rasterstats.zonal_stats(polygons, data, nodata=nodata, affine=transform,
                                             stats=["sum", "std", "median", "majority", "minority",
                                                    "unique", "range", "nodata", "nan", "count"],
                                             geojson_out=True)
    
                    j = 0
                    while j < len(zs):
                        properties_dic = zs[j]['properties']
                        properties_dic.update([('band', band), ('file_name', file)])
                        #properties_list = list(properties_dic.values())
                        zs_bands.append(properties_dic)
                        j = j + 1
                        
                zs_bands_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(zs_bands)
                zs_full_df = zs_full_df.append(zs_bands_df, ignore_index=True)               
    
            # Export df into a csv file
        output_name = 'zonal_stats_' + shp_name + '.csv'
        zs_full_df.to_csv(input_tif_dir + output_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='compute zonal statistics'
    )
    aparser.add_argument(
        '--input-tif-dir',
        default=None
    )
    aparser.add_argument(
        '--shapefile',
        default=None
    )

    args = aparser.parse_args()
    zonal_stats(args.input_tif_dir, args.shapefile)
```

Any idea where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, the script works, the problem was a basic one, the different projection of the tif files and the shapefile.